# Strapi Query custom field filtering

Tags: strapi

I have a collection of handleiding and i want to get them by title

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * handleiding controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::handleiding.handleiding', ({ strapi }) => ({
    async findOne(ctx) {
        const slug = ctx.request.url.split("/").pop();

        // Find the handleiding using the transformed Titel
        const handleiding = await strapi.query('api::handleiding.handleiding').findOne({
            where: {
                Titel: {
                    $eqi: slug
                }
            }
        })

        if (!handleiding) {
            ctx.throw(404, 'Handleiding not found');
        }

        return handleiding;
    },
}));
```

the slug = 'getting-started-with-acf-pro'

and the Titel = 'Getting Started with ACF Pro'

i looked through the documentation but i cant find the correct filtering method, maybe i need to alter the query?

Any suggestions are welcome!